# adduser: /etc/gshadow.: Structure needs cleaning

Tags: linux, centos, permissions, useradd

I am getting the following error when I try to add a new user

```
 sh-4.2$ sudo adduser mbyousaf
adduser: /etc/gshadow.1341: Structure needs cleaning
adduser: cannot lock /etc/gshadow; try again later.
```

I have checked the /etc/passwd file and the above user does not exist

Any solutions?

Comment: This might be independent from `useradd` and is possibly a corrupted file system. [Check this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330742/cannot-remove-file-structure-needs-cleaning) and make sure you create a proper backup!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330742/cannot-remove-file-structure-needs-cleaning

Comment: don't think it related to that, as I am only just trying to create a new user

Comment: Isn't `adduser` a script? `file $( type -p adduser )`, `less $( type -p adduser )`.